# Laravel 5.8 Auth scaffolding redirectTo doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Using the default laravel auth scaffolding in 5.8 in the LoginController theres a variable :

```
  /** * Where to redirect users after login. * * @var string */ 
  protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

I have changed this to '/dashboard' yet it still redirects me to home.

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bumped into this problem back when I started learning it.

Go to '`app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthinticated.php`'. Check that file. I reckon in your case it has something like `return redirect('/home');` which should be changed to appropriate route.

If there is a redirection path there then it will have higher precedence over the $redirectTo property. You can use this function for custom logic also. For example, if the category of the logged in user is customer then send him to somewhere else etc.